# How do I initialize and use exported ReactJS classes from other modules (with WebPack and ES6)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using WebPack and ES6, so I can't use `module.exports` and have to use `export default`. I have a library like this:

```
// helloworld.js
import React from 'react';

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
        test() {
                alert("TEST FROM test()");
        }   
        render() {
                alert("TEST");
                return (
                        <p>Hello, world!</p>
                );  
        }   
}

// THIS WORKS WHEN I REQUIRE THIS MODULE
// var thing = new HelloWorld();
// thing.test();

export default HelloWorld;
```

The commented out portions work when I `var helloworld = require('helloworld.js');`, but I can't figure out how to initialize and use this object outside where I require this.

None of these attempts work. How do I initialize this object and use it?

```
// hello_world.test();
// hello_world.HelloWorld.test();
// var thing = new hello_world();
// var thing = new hello_world.HelloWorld();
```

My main reason is because I need the component in a route using ReactRouter like this and none of these attempts work.

I tried this (bellow) and this tells me to check the render method...

```
ReactDOM.render(
(<BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/helloworld" component={hello_world}/>
        </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>)
```

This (bellow) renders a BLANK PAGE!!!!

```
ReactDOM.render(
(<BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/helloworld" component={hello_world.HelloWorld}/>
        </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>)
```

I'm out of ideas. [This](https://reactjs.org/blog/2014/10/14/introducing-react-elements.html) does not help. Neither does [this](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html). Could please someone lend me some pointers?

EDIT:

Solution was simply to add `default` at the end of require (`var hello_world = require('./helloworld.js').default;`). This works to use this in the route like: `<Route exact path="/helloworld" component={hello_world}/>`.

If you were to use this outside the scope, you would do:

```
var thing = new hello_world();
thing.test();
```

**Working solution:**

```
var hello_world = require('./hello_world.js').default; // Must add default.

// Using it outside a route, with a class method called test().
var thing = new hello_world();
thing.test();

// Using it in a router (ReactRouter with Switch).
ReactDOM.render(
(<BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/helloworld" component={hello_world}/>
        </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>)
, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: "tells me to check the render method" can you share the full error message because that should work, also share how you are importing the `hello_world ` component.

Comment: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Comment: you are exporting HelloWorld by `export default HelloWorld;` ?

Comment: @AlexanderKleinhans `Route` expects a component and `HelloWorld` is component itself. So you can directly use `var HelloWorld = require("./HelloWorld.js")` and then in route pass it as it is `component={HelloWorld}`

Comment: Prakash, `component={HelloWorld}` is the same as `component={hello_world}` because I did `var hello_world = require('hello_world.js');`. This does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var helloworld = require('helloworld.js').default` is working for me. 
Can you check this?
Please guide me if I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the component in a regular jsx file like this:

```
var HelloWorld = require('path/to/HelloWorld.jsx');
...    
<div>
    <HelloWorld></HelloWorld>
</div>
```

Or in a react-router component, with the same require statement like this:

```
var HelloWorld = require('path/to/HelloWorld.jsx');
....
<Route exact path="/helloworld" component={HelloWorld}/>
```

Comment: Okay so that might work for a jsx file, but I want to import a reactjs class. Eventually I would like to import multiple classes.